# Generate 9 random images and put it in a slider/carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

This is my js for generating the random images:

```
var images = ["Image+1", "Image+2", "Image+3"];
  var random = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
  var url = "https://dummyimage.com/250x150/000/fff.jpg&text=" + randomPick;
```

Link to my codepen: https://codepen.io/luca099/pen/RwRabQv

Comment: You're mixing the terms ***"random"*** and ***"shuffle"***. I think the latter is what you need?

Answer (score 0):

The random pick should be inside the loop so it changes